# Resize and crop image

Tags: php, image

I'd like to resize and crop image. 250x250

I can resize it:

```
    $newfilename = "image.jpg";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if (isset ($_FILES['new_image'])){
          $imagename = $newfilename;
          $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
          $target = "img/".$imagename;
          move_uploaded_file($source, $target);  

          $imagepath = $imagename;
          $save = "img/" . $imagepath; 
          $file = "img/" . $imagepath; 

          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 


          $modwidth = 250; 

          $diff = $width / $modwidth;

          $modheight = $height / $diff; 
          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
          imagecopyresized($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ;  

          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ; 

      }
    }
```

But I don't know how to crop it after resizing.
It crops image. And If I have image 10000x10000 it's bad decision

```
 imagecopyresized($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 250, 250, 250) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagecreatetruecolor` to create your NEW image with specified cropped size, then use `imagecopy` to copy it over from OLD to NEW canvas.

Example (not tested):

```
$newfilename = "image.jpg";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if (isset ($_FILES['new_image'])){
      $imagename = $newfilename;
      $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
      $target = "img/".$imagename;
      move_uploaded_file($source, $target);  

      $imagepath = $imagename;
      $save = "img/" . $imagepath; 
      $file = "img/" . $imagepath; 

      list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 


      $modwidth = 250; 

      $diff = $width / $modwidth;

      $modheight = $height / $diff; 
      $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
      $cropped = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 250);
      $cropLeft = 0; // start from left
      $cropTop = 0; // start from top

      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
      imagecopyresized($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ;  
      imagecopy($cropped, $image, 0, 0, $cropLeft, $cropTop, $modwidth, $modheight);

      imagejpeg($cropped, $save, 100); // save cropped image
      // imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ;  // save resized image

  }
}
```

Comment: Set `$cropped = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight);`

Comment: It only crops original image

Comment: Then change `imagecopy` to `imagecopy($cropped, $tn, 0, 0, $cropLeft, $cropTop, $modwidth, $modheight);
`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use croppie. The github url is http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/
I have used it and it works great

Comment: He is asking for a back end solution, not another npm package.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use PHP to get the images and echo them in HTML and apply a specific width/height to them.

Comment: That's not at all what he's asking for, and to be honest, that's a very lazy and wasteful way to do it.